# Require is not defined nodejs bot discord

Tags: node.js

I have a problem I am in the process of developing a Discord bot and I have put the module fs and vm to include other JS to avoid an accumulation in my index.js but when I launch my bot the console tells me that require is not defined can you help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: could you show us some code and tell us where the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.
It's my code :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYaFD.png
This error apparead in my debugger on visual code studio.
And it's my code for the modules fs and vm : 
var reponse = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/commandes/réponse.js");
vm.runInThisContext(reponse);
I hope you have a solution
Thanks